# Mechanical Contactor for High Voltage DC - Substitute with Semiconductor

Tags: mosfet, switches, high-voltage, solid-state-relay, contactor

To switch 1kV DC at 5A, I usually use a mechanical [contactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contactor) (<- Wikipedia) that switches both highside and lowside of a resistive load.

Any suggestions on a semiconductor (or non-mechanical part) to do the job? For me, especially the high side switch makes it difficult.

Both highside *and* lowside have to be switched to meet the guidelines.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Keywords: IGBT, GTO, SiC MOSFET.

Comment: IGBT would work. Solid state relays. Maybe GaN MOSFETs.

Comment: How to drive the high side gate?

Comment: Use isolated gate driver and isolated piwer DC/DC supply. I think, there are even combo of both.

Comment: What guidelines? For example, you are unlikely to meet any safety guidelines with a solid-state isolation device.

Comment: Just to reinforce @transistor's comment : unless there is a separate, independent, mechanical isolator ... don't!

Comment: Thank you, and yes, you are absolutely right about that. The idea is to use 1 mechanical switch for safety guidelines, and several channels with their own solid-state switches that fan out from there.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcQAIJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Combined relay / switch + SSR.*

Keep the relay or switch for safe isolation and lockout. A high-voltage DC SSR can be installed on either or both legs of the circuit. You need to meet:

- Blocking voltage (> 1k V and maybe > 2 kV for safety) for your 1 kV supply.
- Isolation voltage (> 2 kV) to prevent insulation breakdown between the high voltage and low voltage circuits.
- Switching current (> 5 A) and allow for any surge due to cold resistance of the load, etc.).

A quick search found [Sensitron](https://sensitron.com/ssr.htm) devices, for example.

Your control system can now turn on RLY1 and leave it on in normal operation while using the SSR for normal control. This gives you the advantages of low cycles and wear and tear on the relay while maintaining the ability to isolate safely.